# Issue with out.flush() with a webserver

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, flush

I am using `out.flush()` in a jsp to update regularly the results of some execution in the browser. It is a long execution, about 10 minutes, and I don't want the browser to look like it is waiting forever. (It also avoids timeout errors).

It works fine, when connecting directly to tomcat port, but when I go through an apache web server it is not working (it is probably because the flush now is sent to the web server and the web server doesn't flush until some buffer is filled).

Any idea how could I achieve the same result I was having connecting to tomcat port, but going throufh a web server?

I'm looking for a simple solution (if possible), I mean not ajax or launching a new thread in tomcat and then refreshing the browser regularly, as they will imply a lot of changes.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a configuration parameter in the [mod_jk plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html) that addresses this problem.

The option is : `JkOptions +FlushPackets`

Having this option set, Apache web server will flush anything that it receives from Tomcat.

Comment: Correct, glad it works for you. As this does "flush Apache's connection buffer after each AJP packet chunk received from Tomcat" the performance impact may be drastic. If that should ever hit you the obvious measure would of course be to extract that long running operation and set up a dedicated Tomcat endpoint just for that (disabling `FlushPackets` for the rest).

Answer (score 0):

Increase the [Apache timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/mod/core.html#timeout) to 10min?

```
#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 600
```

Comment: But then the browser will be waiting for 10 minutes with no change. I'd like to avoid the effect that it is waiting forever. If I flush regularly I have no timeout problems between apache web server and tomcat.

Comment: The Apache timeout just needs to be higher than your flush intervals.

Comment: So let's say I am flushing each 20 secs, what timeout should Apache have?

Comment: More than 20s, the default is 60s.

Comment: I cannnot change the Apache config, but I will try to get the change done and update. Let's say I put 21s. Pages that take 30s to render will timeout? (there are many other applications in this apache, that may get affected)

Comment: If you don't have control over the Apache config I suggest you find out what the current timeout setting is and adjust the `flush` interval accordingly.

Comment: I found another option that is exactly what I wanted (I will post it). Thanks a lot for your help.